# Automate the boring stuff- Comma Code: Why doesn't my code work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on the Comma Code problem, and I came up with the following code:

```
def comma_code(mylist):
    for i in mylist:
         if i!=len(mylist):
              print (mylist[i]+', ',end="")
         elif i==len(mylist):
              print ('and ' + mylist[i])
spam = ['apple', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
comma_code( spam )
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vivianspro/PycharmProjects/helloworld/ATBS chapter 4 List", line 61, in <module>
    comma_code( spam )
  File "/Users/vivianspro/PycharmProjects/helloworld/ATBS chapter 4 List", line 57, in comma_code
    print (mylist[i]+', ',end="")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I've also written the code below through trial and error and magically it worked but I don't understand why on Earth it worked:

```
def comma_code(mylist):
    for i in range(0, len(mylist)-1):
        if i != len( mylist ):
        print( mylist[i] + ', ', end="" ) 
    a=len(mylist)
    while a:
          print('and ' + mylist[i+1])
          break
spam = ['apple', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
comma_code( spam )
```

For the `while` loop, why does `mylist[i+1]` works, but not simply `mylist[i]`?

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read without proper formatting. Please format it so we can read it.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to upload the picture of the code but it doesn't let me... i'll try to upload it again

Comment: Don't upload pictures of code. I fixed the formatting in your question, take a look at the [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks a lot! @L3viathan . i'm super new to stackoverflow but i'll figure these stuffs out

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating over a list and expect indices, while actually getting the list's elements:

```
def comma_code(mylist):
    for i in mylist:
```

Instead, if you really need the indices, you can use `enumerate`:

```
def comma_code(mylist):
    for i, item in enumerate(mylist):
```

But there's no need to handle the indices directly like that. How about this:

```
def comma_code(mylist):
    for item in mylist[:-1]:
        print(item + ', ', end="")
    print('and', mylist[-1])

spam = ['apple', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
comma_code(spam)
```

This doesn't yet handle the case of an empty list (and has weird output for a list with only one element), but I'll leave that as an exersize to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop `for i in mylist:`,`i` accepts the value of each list element in turn, not the indices of the elements. The expression `mylist[i]` is off course incorrect at that point, since the element is already `i`. The comparison `i==len(mylist)` is meaningless for the same reason.

The loop `for i in range(0, len(mylist)-1):` iterates over the indices from 0 to `len(mylist)-2` since `range` excludes the last element. That means that when your loop is over, `i ==  len(mylist)-2`, which is the index of the second to last element.

The subsequent `while` loop is not really a loop at all. It breaks out in the first iteration after `print('and ' + mylist[i+1])`. It's just a lot of cruft to print the last element of the list. Remember that at this point `i` is the second to last index after the `for` loop ended, so `i + 1` is just the last element's index.

All this code can be reduced to a one liner:

```
print(*mylist[:-1], 'and ' + mylist[-1], sep=', ')
```

or

```
print(f'{", ".join(mylist[:-1])}, and {mylist[-1]}')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. when I do                                                 
    for i in range(0, len(mylist)) the loop seems to iterate from the first to the last index(including the last item), which is confusing because I thought it is supposed to end before the last index.

Comment: @Vivian. The last index in a list is `len(mylist) - 1`. The first index is zero, not 1. The last element of a range is exclusive. That means that `range(len(mylist))` contains the elements `0, 1, 2, ..., len(mylist) - 2, len(mylist) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']


def commacode(list):
    lastitem = ''.join(spam[-1:])
    return ', '.join(spam[:-1]) + ' and ' + lastitem


print(commacode(spam))
```

Comment: Hi Maki! For answer to be complete, you probably need to live short explanation how your code works.

Comment: Please also note that this question has been answered correctly with a detailed explanation of why the original code didn't work back in 2019.